# How to find element and change it's class (font awesome icon) on success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, font-awesome

I want to change a icon for an element on success (Ajax), here is how my icons looks:

```
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" MessageID="@item.ID"></i>


$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("getClass", "app")',
  type: "GET",
  data: { id: ClassID },
  success: function (data) { // How to get element above i change it's class  } );
```

Acctually I'm wondering what is proper way of getting this element which contains `class = "fa fa-check"`.. I tried few things but It does not work :(

Thanks guys!
Cheers!

Comment: why you dont added an ID to the element and than remove and added a class when needed

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif I added Id to the element as you can see MessageID, but I don't kow how to get that element on success

Answer (score -1):

```
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" MessageID="@item.ID"></i>


$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("getClass", "app")',
  type: "GET",
  data: { id: ClassID },
  success: function (data) {
    $("[MessageID='"+data.id+"']").removeClass('fa-check').addClass('fa-times'); } );
```

Comment: This will affect all the elements with `fa` class, which is not the required solution

Comment: it's an example as there is no other element with fa class here he can change what he want like adding another class..

Comment: @ChiragSwadia Exactlly, that's why I added MessageID on each icon, so I can get element with MessageID value and change that's value, because I'm making get for each item.ID ..

Comment: @billy_56 you haven't mentioned that in question I've edited the answer

Answer (score -1):

For changing the icon you can easily do something like this in your icon click event, inside the success callback.

```
$(this).find($(".fa")).removeClass('fa-check').addClass('fa-something');
```

For more information, take a look at the below jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/pjQP7/10/

Comment: $(this) refers to what here? in your fiddle its inside a click event, but here there is no

Comment: I am just giving an example. He will obviously write the ajax call inside any event. For eg click

Comment: good but you must pay attention that this inside ajax refers to the jqXHR object not the element of the event

Comment: $(this) will not be used directly inside xhr/ajax. Its reference will be stored in the event and later on used inside success. Please don't go into that much detail. I am just giving a different example to help solve this issue.